# How to activate a filter only when a cell is not blank?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Below is a script that activates and creates a filter when cell 'B2' is edited.
But I want to add a clear function to clear all filters when cell 'B2' is Blank.
This script should work when cell 'B2' is not empty:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sheetName = "Sheet1";
  var editCell = "B2";

  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (range.getA1Notation() == editCell && sheet.getSheetName() == sheetName) {
    updatefilter(sheet);
  } else {
    // do something
  }
}

function updatefilter(sheet) {
  sheet.getRange('B3').activate();
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenFormulaSatisfied("=(B3:B=$B$2)").build();
  var filter = sheet.getFilter();
  if (!filter) {
    filter = sheet.getRange("A3:H").createFilter();
  }
  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(2, criteria);
};
```

Any idea how to add a "Clear All" Filter when the cell is blank?

Here is a working link to a Spreadsheet -

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HT-I59RZ0qe-1jzQ2TcRsWva50I74FKSo4PvpxujH2g/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If the function works at all it will only work for user edits and it only performs functions that require no permissions

Comment: Please post [mcve] in the question, NoCode=>NoHelp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

You can add an `if` condition to check whether the user **deleted** the current value of `B2` or **replaced** it with a **non-empty** value.

- If the user replaced the value of `B2` with a non-empty value, execute the `updatefilter` function.
- if the user deleted the current value of `B2`, clear the filter in `Sheet1`.

### Solution:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sheetName = "Sheet1";
  var editCell = "B2";

  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (range.getA1Notation() == editCell && sheet.getSheetName() == sheetName) {
     
     // *** New code starts ***
     if(e.range.getValue()!=''){
        updatefilter(sheet);
     }
     else {
        sheet.getFilter().remove();
     };
     // *** New code ends***
}
}

function updatefilter(sheet) {
  sheet.getRange('B3').activate();
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenFormulaSatisfied("=(B3:B=$B$2)").build();
  var filter = sheet.getFilter();
  if (!filter) {
    filter = sheet.getRange("A3:H").createFilter();
  }
  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(2, criteria);
};
```